# How to determine whether bash was invoked with --norc or --rcfile?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Is there a way to determine whether the current shell was invoked with either the `--norc` flag or the `--rcfile` (aka `--init-file`) flag?  And if the latter was used, what was its argument?

PS: I know that, on Linux, I may be able to scrape the contents of `/proc/$$/cmdline`, so for this question I am interested in answers that do not depend on the flavor of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask `ps` for the current shell's arguments and look for those options:

```bsh
if [[ $(ps -o args= -p $$) =~ (--norc|--rcfile|--init-file) ]]
then 
  echo yes
fi
```